# Error al crear una coleccion en firestore con javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firestore

estoy con un proyecto creando una pagina web con firebase, he realizado el login y al registrarse lo hace bien y guarda los datos. Ahora estoy creando una colección nueva para Equipos (con firestore) y me da error al crearla.

La cosa es así, yo inicio sesión y entro a la pagina de mis Equipos para crear uno nuevo, relleno los datos y me da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi `login.js` es este

```
import { db, auth, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut, onAuthStateChanged } from './firebaseAuth.js';

login?.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    //Obtenemos los valores de los campos
    const emailL = emailLogin.value;
    const passwordL = passwordLogin.value;

    // Validar que el correo y la contraseña no estén vacíos
    if (emailL === '' || passwordL === '') {
        alert('Por favor ingresa tu correo y contraseña');
        return;
    }

    // Autenticar al usuario con el correo electrónico y la contraseña
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, emailL, passwordL)
        .then((userCredential) => {

            // Almacenar información del usuario en variable global
            currentUser = userCredential.user;
            // Iniciar sesión
            alert('Bienvenido');
            window.location.href = 'index.html';

           
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert('Error al iniciar sesión: ' + error.message);
        });

});


//Escuchamos el evento de cambio de estado de inicio de sesion
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
        // Usuario iniciado
        currentUser = user;
        const uid = currentUser.uid;
        console.log("El id del usuario registrado: " + uid);
        //Si hay un usuario autenticado, ocultamos el boton de inicio de sesion y mostramos el dropDown de perfil
        btnLogin?.classList.add('d-none');
        dropPerfil?.classList.remove('d-none');


    } else {
        //Si no hay usuario registrado hacemos lo contrario
        currentUser = null;
        btnLogin?.classList.remove('d-none');
        dropPerfil?.classList.add('d-none');
    }
});

export{ currentUser };
```

y este `misEquipos.js`

```
import { db, setDoc, collection } from './firebaseAuth.js';
import Equipos from './js/Clases/Equipos.js';
import { currentUser } from './login.js';


//Obtener valores de los campos de entrada registro
const formulario = document.getElementById('formularioEquipos');
const nombreEquipo = document.getElementById('nombreEquipo');
const paisEquipo = document.getElementById('paisEquipo');
const logoEquipo = document.getElementById('logoEquipo');
const instagramEquipo = document.getElementById('instagramEquipo');
const webEquipo = document.getElementById('webEquipo');
const twitchEquipo = document.getElementById('twitchEquipo');
const discordEquipo = document.getElementById('discordEquipo');

//Agregamos el eventListener y submit al formulario
formulario.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Obtén el ID del usuario actual
    const userId = currentUser ? currentUser.uid : null;

    //obtenemos los valores de de los campos
    const nombre = nombreEquipo.value.trim();
    const pais = paisEquipo.value.trim();
    const logo = logoEquipo.value;
    const instagram = instagramEquipo.value.trim();
    const web = webEquipo.value.trim();
    const twitch = twitchEquipo.value.trim();
    const discord = discordEquipo.value.trim();

    // Crear objeto Equipos
    const equipo = new Equipos(nombre, pais, "", instagram, web, twitch, discord);

    //Validar que los datos no esten vacios
    if (nombre === "" || pais === "" || instagram === "" || web === "" || twitch === "" || discord === "") {
        alert("Completa todos los campos");
        return;
    }

    //Accedemos a la coleccion Equipos para guardar los datos
        const registrarEquipo = collection(db, 'Equipos');
        setDoc(registrarEquipo, {
            nombre: equipo.nombre,
            pais: equipo.pais,
            logo: equipo.logo,
            instagram: equipo.instagram,
            web: equipo.web,
            twitch: equipo.twitch,
            discord: equipo.discord, 
            jefe: userId
        }).then(() => {
            alert("Equipo registrado correctamente");

        }).catch((error) => {
            //Muestra mensaje de error
            alert("Error al guardar los datos: ", error.message);
        });

});
```

Me podeis echar una mano???

Comment: Si lees la documentación, verás que [`setDoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_lite.md#setdoc) espera como parámetro un `DocumentReference`, pero tú le estarías pasando una colección. Me refiero a esta línea: `setDoc(registrarEquipo, {` Si vas a pasar una colección, debes usar [`addDoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_lite.md#adddoc).

Comment: Solucionado, gracias!! lo he cambiado e importado y ya funciona

Answer (score 0):

Si lees la documentación, verás que [`setDoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_lite.md#setdoc) espera como parámetro un `DocumentReference`, pero tú le estarías pasando `registrarEquipo` que es una colección.

Si vas a pasar una colección, debes usar [`addDoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_lite.md#adddoc)

Poniéndolo así debería funcionar:

```
//Accedemos a la coleccion Equipos para guardar los datos
    const registrarEquipo = collection(db, 'Equipos');
    addDoc(registrarEquipo, {
        nombre: equipo.nombre,
        // ...
```

Si lo que necesitas crear realmente es un documento, entonces debes proporcionar su ID o hacer que el mismo se genere de forma automática. Considera revisar el apartado [**Agrega datos a Cloud Firestore**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=es-419) para más detalles y ejemplos de uso.